# Why in button tag onclick=methodname is not giving output but onclick=operation gives output

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the below code if I change background color of Submit button with `onclick="document.getElementById('s').style.background='green'"` then it changes perfectly but if I do it with function call then it doesn't work which I tried for Clear button. I have commented the functions. Answer me if you have any solution for this.

```js
function open() {
    x = document.getElementById('s');
    x.style.background = "green";
}

function close() {
    document.getElementById('c').style.background = "red";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Events-code with me</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Changing style</h1>
    <button id="s" onclick="document.getElementById('s').style.background='green'">Submit</button>
    <button id="c" onclick="close()">Clear</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`close()` is a method on the window object when you name your function as close and you called on click. the browser engine called the windows `close()` method, not your close method. A simple way to solve this is to rename your function.

```js
function open() {
    x = document.getElementById('s');
    x.style.background = "green";
}

function closeX() {
    document.getElementById('c').style.background = "red";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Events-code with me</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Changing style</h1>
    <button id="s" onclick="document.getElementById('s').style.background='green'">Submit</button>
    <button id="c" onclick="closeX()">Clear</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Events-code with me</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Changing style</h1>
    <button id="s" onclick="openX();">Submit</button>
    <button id="c" onclick="closeX();">Clear</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openX() {
            x = document.getElementById('s');
            x.style.background = "green";
        }

        function closeX() {
            document.getElementById('c').style.background = "red";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually when you use `open();` and `close();`, it will call `window.open();` and `window.close();`. In JavaScript, all global variables (like `document`)and functions(for eg `alert()`) belongs to window object (as `window.document`and `window.alert()`).

To make those functions work, you must rename them, which I have done above.

Answer (score 0):

The open() method is a default method of JS to opens a new browser window or a new tab, so change it with any other method name, for example

```
function openModal() {
    x = document.getElementById('s');
    x.style.background = "green";
}
<button id="s" onclick="openModal">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'tried ur code with function call i'ts because open() and close() are an inbuilt function in javascript and don't forget to write ur js code in  tag :)

Give an another function name instead of open and close

[image]

Comment: NIce work Tanmay, but post it inside `HTML snippet` (button right next to the `Image` button labelled `<>`). It helps other people to use that code without rewriting it. Are you using Notepad++?

Comment: Yeah sure . thank you for that. No, i' am using Visual Studio code.